# Comparing file and printing the matches and differences

Tags: file, awk, comparison

I'm trying to compare 2 files and print the output like below:

F1:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
q|w|e|r||f|
```

F2:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g
q|w|e|r|t|f|u
```

output:

```
f1 - a|b|c|d|e|f|g - f2 - a|b|c|d|e|f|g  - All columns are matching
f1 - q|w|e|r||f| - f2 - q|w|e|r|t|f|u - Column 5 and 7 are not matching
```

Comment: why don't you use `diff` and `comm` for this? 
No need to reinvent the wheel!!!

Answer (score 0):

The following does exactly what was asked... (noting two spaces before "- All" and one space in the not matching case, and f1 and f2 are lowercase). If we want to use the name of the files instead of f1 and f2, the FILENAME variable is available

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS = "|"
    split("", f1)
}

NR == FNR { # this is true only for the first file processed
    f1[FNR] = $0
    next
}

$0 == f1[FNR] { # with the second file, if lines are equal...
    print "f1 - " f1[FNR] " - f2 - " $0 "  - All columns are matching"
    next
}

{ # if the lines are not equal, split and find the columns not equal
    sz = split(f1[FNR], f)
    if (NF > sz)
        sz = NF
    c = ""
    for (i=1; i<=sz; ++i)
            if (f[i] != $i) {
                    c = i++
                    break
            }
    for (; i<=sz; ++i)
            if (f[i] != $i)
                    c = c " and " i
    print "f1 - " f1[FNR] " - f2 - " $0 " - Column " c " are not matching"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It works as expected. But i try it with unsorted files it is not working. Can you help sorting?

Comment: @Rivion -- Hm.... The code was written the way it was because your sample data seems to show the files are "ordered."  The simple way to answer the question is to say "run `sort` on the files first?", but it's likely that this is a non-trivial problem because it's difficult to know how the files should be ordered/sorted when any of the characters in the list might be left out of either side. Perhaps you could frame your question/data in such a way that it helps us understand what you are looking for?